# i want to have a vertical scrollbar in my bootstrap table by giving the height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How to have a vertical scrollbar in the bootstrap table?
I have given a height of 100px but the table is taking more than 100 px and scroll is not coming for the table

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to apply the scroll;

```
    overflow-x: auto;
```

or

```
    overflow-y: auto;
```

Then finally to prevent movement in the opposite axis you should disregard whitespace.

```
    white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: if apply overflow-x: auto to table it is not working.because I cant set the specific height to the bootstrap table

Comment: <table class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-xs-3">Item No</th>
          <th class="col-xs-6">Item Name</th>
          <th class="col-xs-3">Cost</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="New">
      </tbody>
    </table>

Comment: That is useless, you have no css, etc.  How can I see what you have tried, are trying, what it currently looks like and how you want it to look like.